# Firebase Auth Error While Trying To Create An Account

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I haven't touched this code since August and it was working fine, but since I started back on it yesterday, I've been getting this error:

> W/TAG: createUserWithEmail:failure

> com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ Unable to resolve host "www.googleapis.com":No address associated with hostname ]

All of my dependencies are set up correctly. I checked countless times as well as spending hours on YouTube, redownloaded the json file, updated Android Studio and my emulators. This is my last resort. I hope someone can help. Here's my code

```
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                        Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Sign up success! Taking you to login...",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        
                         
                    } else {
                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                        Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    
                    }
      }
            })
    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
            Log.d(TAG, "FAIL");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Does your emulator have internet? Check the icon/s in the top right

Comment: Do you have the correct security rules?

Comment: I got this error when there is no Internet connection. Yeah, there is ambiguity in such error ,it may be a firebase bug preventing auth api from issuing a "no connection a error" clearly.

Answer (score 0):

The last time I used firebase auth I used this code:

```
AuthUI.IdpConfig googleIdp = new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder()
                        .build();

                startActivityForResult(AuthUI.getInstance()
                        .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                        .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                        .setTosAndPrivacyPolicyUrls("Política de privacidad", "http://twitter.com")
                        .setAvailableProviders(Arrays.asList(new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
                                facebookIdp, googleIdp))
                        .setTheme(R.style.GreenTheme)
                        .setLogo(R.drawable.img_multi_login)
                        .build(), RC_SIGN_IN);
```

And for the result:

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Welcome", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } 
}
```

And use an AuthStateListener to change the data of the user if something changed or if the user is logged or not.

I think this is the easiest way to implement firebase auth on Android.